# Find points within a polygon - which now is a 2D array - in Python

Tags: python, arrays, polygon, shapes

I have searched SO for an answer and I think there is none.

I have a 2D array that once plotted on a pcolormesh looks like the image below: 
[image]

It is not a simple polygon, i.e. a square, but a rather complicated polygon. Ignore the varying color on the edge and suppose that it is either 0 (where it is white) and 1 (where it is red). It defines a lat/lon region.
I then have the black dots, which are point-location.

I need to identify which black point falls in the region (the red part, where I have 1's). I only need the total count of black points falling in that region.

There's gotta be an easy way to do it, but I failed to find it so far.

Comment: Why don't you iterate in the 2D array and check the color value for each point. if its equal to 1 increase a counter. Can't think of anything simpler than that.

Comment: Thanks! The resolution of the 2D array is 0.25 degree. The resolution of the lat/lon data can be much finer. I could - of course - round them up and do the looping. I did think about this. However, I have a lot of points and regions, and I was hoping to find something simple like applying a mask or on those lines, or it would take really really long.

Comment: I think my question wasn't clear - I need to count which black points fall in the red area, not how many red points I have. I have corrected the text.

Comment: If your polygon is not convex I don't think there is an easy shortcut.

Comment: Ah i see what you want to do now, and its indeed not that simple. What i would try to do (if its possible of course), would be to first plot all the region as red (just non zero values). Count the points that define the whole region, then plot the black points, but not as color. Instead of plotting black colored points you need to plot them as white points. This way you will be able to recount the red points and the difference should give you the black points that are falling onto the area. There should be no other (probable) way of doing something like this.

Comment: Interesting simple procedure. I will see how rough is compared to the resolution of the point.

Comment: Ah and i just thought of another way, but it should be a really bad (performance wise) way. You can assign your points into python sets. What you should store in the sets should be something like a string (strings are hashable) containing both x and y coords so that you can tell which point it is. If you can create two sets one with the red points and one with the black points, a simple intersect between them should give you just the common points of both sets, which are the black points on the red area. Check here how to create sets https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: This seems really interesting!